# c++ Not able to add an element in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am fairly new to c++. I am trying to add another element in the array. The function should change the array and the number of items in the array after the addEntry function is completed, but it doesn't. If I use the display function to show the array, only the original array is shown. Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int MAXSIZE = 10;           // total size of array

void display(string[], int);
void addEntry(string[], int&);

int main()
{
    string name[MAXSIZE] = {"raj","casey","tom","phil"};
    int numEntries = 4;      // number of elements in the array
    string choice;           // the user choice to add an element or display or exit

    cout<<numEntries<<" names were read in."<<endl;

    do
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Enter menu choice (display, add, quit): ";
        getline(cin,choice);

        if (choice == "display")
        {
            display(name, numEntries);
            cout<<endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "add")
        {
            addEntry(name, numEntries);
            cout<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"bye"<<endl;
        }

    } while (choice!="quit");

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}


void display(string name[], int numEntries)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
    {
        cout<<name[i]<<endl;
    }
    return;
}

void addEntry(string name[], int& numEntries)
{
    if (numEntries<MAXSIZE-1)
    {
        numEntries++;
        cout<<"Enter name of the person to add: ";
        getline(cin,name[numEntries]);
        cout << "Entry added.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"There is not enough space is in the array to add a new entry!";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a debugger, learn how to use it, before asking here!

Comment: You don't seem to understand how arrays work in C++. I would suggest starting slowly with a C++ tutorial to get a better understanding of what you can and can't do.

Comment: `Comments.push_back("Obligatory comment about how using vectors are better");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works, you are just pointing the the wrong location in your array in addEntry. Remember that arrays in C++ are 0-based, try incrementing the value of numEntries AFTER inserting the element in your array, for example:

```
void addEntry(string name[], int& numEntries)
{
    if (numEntries<MAXSIZE)
    {
        cout<<"Enter name of the person to add: ";
        getline(cin,name[numEntries++]);
        cout << "Entry added.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"There is not enough space is in the array to add a new entry!";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I knew about the array being 0-based, I just got confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
getline(cin,name[numEntries]);
```

`numEntries` is the number of valid entries in your array. `name[numEntries]` is the element that is following the last valid entry. Use `name[numEntries-1]`.

Or even better, use `std::vector` instead of C arrays, after all, you are writing in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is in the following lines:

```
  numEntries++;
  cout<<"Enter name of the person to add: ";
  getline(cin,name[numEntries]);
```

You need to increment `numEntries` after the call to `getline`. Use:

```
  cout<<"Enter name of the person to add: ";
  if ( getline(cin,name[numEntries]) )
  {
     // Increment only if getline was successful.
     numEntries++;
  }
```